# Is it possible to manage the receipt of a Connection for a transaction in Spring (the mode Open Session in View)?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, transactions, java-11

I use Spring boot to simplify working with the configuration.

When the RestController receives a request for it automatically (this is the default action), Connection is allocated from the datasource and until the transit is completed, Connection is open. (at least I have such information, you can correct it).

In is a mode: **Open Session In View**.

**OSIV** in **Spring Boot** is implemented using the **OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor** web request interceptor class. Unlike pure Spring, it is enabled here by default.

But before executing the transactional method, this request may be delayed on the business logic layer for processing, and the connection is "idle". This leads to Connection leaks.

It seems that you can control the output of connection when using Srpingboot .

But how is this done ?

Please give an example.

Answer (score 1):

First. You should **disable** the mode  **Open Session in View**.

```sh
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
```

Then, you should use the **@EntityGraph** annotation.

```java
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = "departments")
    Optional<User> findDetailedByUsername(String username);


    Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);

}
```

Beware of using **Hibernate.initialize()**, because it forms not one, but several queries to get related tables.